# How to "ignore" arguments

Tags: python, parameters, arguments

I'm making a task manager in python that uses a json file as an archive and to save the informations that the user gives to the program i made a python file with different functions that manages those inputs.

And then when the infos are collected I made a function that adds those infos to the json file

```py
import json

def setTitle():
    #collects user's input

    appendJson(task=userInput)

def setDescription():
     #collects user's input

     appendJson(description=userInput)

def appendJson (task, description):
     #generate the json item
```

When I run the code it gives me an error because I didn't mention the other arguments.
So basically I should've wrote `appendJson(task=userInput, description=bla bla)` and the problem is that the code doesn't work if I wrote that.

**So is there a way to omit the second argument in the function call?**

If you did not understand something tell me in the comments
Thanks <3

Comment: What is the error that you're seeing? Can you copy and paste it here?

Comment: Give `description` a default value e.g. `def appendJson (task, description=None):`

Comment: @Mathchiller appendJson() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'task' and 'description'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it,

Assing a default value to the arguments like this:

```py
def appendJson(task="default value", descripiton="defaultvalue"):
```

You can also use

```py
def appendJson(task="Hello World", descripiton=None):
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to call the function without having to provide every argument each time, you can use a keyword argument instead:

```
def appendJson(task, description=None):
     #generate the json item
```

In that case, the first argument will always be interpreted as *task* and you can optionally supply *description* via appendJson(task, description="randomdescription").

If you want to have both optional, you can make both arguments a keyword argument:

```
def appendJson(task=None, description=None):
     #generate the json item
```